# how not to include empty values in logic

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have this on my front-end (html)

```
<label for="sunday">Sunday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="sunday" name="sunday" value="1">
<label for="monday">Monday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="monday" name="monday" value="2">
<label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="tuesday" value="3">
<label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" name="wednesday" value="4">
<label for="thursday">Thursday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="thursday" name="thursday" value="5">
<label for="friday">Friday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="friday" name="friday" value="6">
<label for="saturday">Saturday</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="saturday" value="7">
```

then in my backend, i want to submit the ones that have been selected into the database. So i was thinking of writing something along the lines of:

```
var dates = {
        monday: req.body.monday,
        tuesday: req.body.tuesday,
        wednesday: req.body.wednesday,
        thursday: req.body.thursday,
        friday: req.body.friday,
        saturday: req.body.saturday,
        sunday: req.body.sunday
    }

    for (const item in dates) {
        console.log(item.value)
        if (item.value == undefined) {
            item = false
            console.log("undefined")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Barmar well thats what i'm trying to figure out how to do. But maybe now thinking it may be better to do that from the frontend. but still, how would i only submit the ones that have been checked?

Comment: In JavaScript, all arrays are truthy. Use `if (dates.split("").length > 0)`

Comment: No need for `split()`, just `if (dates)`

Comment: My earlier comment misunderstood the question, I thought this JS was on the client, not the server.

Comment: `if (dates.split(''))` will always be true because an empty array is also truthy. But instead of `if (dates.split('').length)`, the more straight-forward `if (dates)` should do it too. However, the values may be `undefined` and not an empty string, and then you'd get e.g. `12undefined4undefinedundefined7` - so better use `req.body.monday ?? ''` etc. - An easier way might be using the same `name="weekdays[]"` for all of them (with different `value` of course) and then just accessing the `req.body.weekdays` array. (Note this requires `extended: true` in the bodyparser configuration.)

Comment: @Barmar thanks for you reply. i posted a new question it may be easier to answer if you are familiar with sql. I think it would be an easier way to do it, breaks it down more. thanks!

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for you reply. i posted a new question it may be easier to answer if you are familiar with sql. I think it would be an easier way to do it, breaks it down more. thanks!